# Building a long table using divs with overflow. (twitter-bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a table with divs. The table should be very long, so I have to use overflow auto/hidden.

Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/gj7vm/

The problem is, when I'm trying to add a title for `.group` div, everything suddenly breaks  (http://jsfiddle.net/ata5U/1/). (each `.group` div should contain other divs, just like table, but here i'm just starting with simple `.title` div, which should have fixed height)

How can this be fixed? 
Also, are there any good examples of something similar to what I'm trying to build (a long html table with overflow:hidden/auto)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to build a table with divs, why don't you use CSS table display values? They will make your divs act like table cells.

Here's an example of the CSS:

```
div#screen {
  height: 120px;
  display: table;
}
#screen .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.group {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="screen" class="well well-large">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-title">foobar</div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et diam risus. Proin eu pellentesque massa. Sed non turpis nunc, ultrices lacinia risus. Nunc et massa nec nulla commodo fermentum. Ut sit amet est id erat auctor pellentesque id non neque. Aliquam lacinia luctus condimentum. Phasellus fringilla metus at lectus auctor venenatis. Phasellus nec nulla at risus elementum feugiat ut sit amet tortor. Mauris egestas sapien non purus eleifend suscipit. Cras tortor metus, porta ac ultrices eget, sagittis a augue. Nullam facilisis, lacus iaculis condimentum placerat, mi metus pretium justo, a scelerisque enim felis id eros. Integer dictum, mi et posuere dapibus, risus ante ullamcorper tortor, sit amet adipiscing libero massa ut neque.
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-title">foobar</div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et diam risus. Proin eu pellentesque massa. Sed non turpis nunc, ultrices lacinia risus. Nunc et massa nec nulla commodo fermentum. Ut sit amet est id erat auctor pellentesque id non neque. Aliquam lacinia luctus condimentum. Phasellus fringilla metus at lectus auctor venenatis. Phasellus nec nulla at risus elementum feugiat ut sit amet tortor. Mauris egestas sapien non purus eleifend suscipit. Cras tortor metus, porta ac ultrices eget, sagittis a augue. Nullam facilisis, lacus iaculis condimentum placerat, mi metus pretium justo, a scelerisque enim felis id eros. Integer dictum, mi et posuere dapibus, risus ante ullamcorper tortor, sit amet adipiscing libero massa ut neque.  </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-title">foobar</div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et diam risus. Proin eu pellentesque massa. Sed non turpis nunc, ultrices lacinia risus. Nunc et massa nec nulla commodo fermentum. Ut sit amet est id erat auctor pellentesque id non neque. Aliquam lacinia luctus condimentum. Phasellus fringilla metus at lectus auctor venenatis. Phasellus nec nulla at risus elementum feugiat ut sit amet tortor. Mauris egestas sapien non purus eleifend suscipit. Cras tortor metus, porta ac ultrices eget, sagittis a augue. Nullam facilisis, lacus iaculis condimentum placerat, mi metus pretium justo, a scelerisque enim felis id eros. Integer dictum, mi et posuere dapibus, risus ante ullamcorper tortor, sit amet adipiscing libero massa ut neque. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8g8sW/1/

When you use these, you don't need overflow: auto because the divs will act like table cells and automatically stretch to fit their content.

For more info: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/

If there's a reason that you don't want to use CSS tables (e.g. browser support), please say so, but they seemed like the easiest and most obvious choice for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The core point was overflow:auto/hidden because it will be very very long table (2000-3000px) and the height of each row should be fixed (about 20-30px). So I cannot rely on this solution, but thank you anyway +1.

Comment: So each "table cell" .group within a row needs to be a fixed height. Does that mean that .group needs to be set to overflow: hidden? Does the text inside the .group divs wrap, or should it all be on one line? The containing div #screen needs to automatically stretch to fit all of the rows, but the rows themselves have overflow: hidden. Is that correct? I'm trying to visualize what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Somehow I almost managed to got it "right" (http://jsfiddle.net/cPUNt/). Basically, the only place where I need `overflow:hidden` is `#screen` div. Because this div contains the table (which I'm trying to build using divs) and I want to hide the rest of this table because it's very long. But the cells will not have any text inside. I'm going to use them later for visualizing time-intervals (by highlighting matched cells). I'm kind of okay with my current solution, except I have to calculate `width` for parent's elements.